# Android: a pop-up dialog style window

Tags: android, popupwindow

Right now I have a popupWindow being dynamically populated with a check-list.
This window pops up when the user taps the check-list button on screen.

However, the items in the background are not being faded out and they seem are still click-able.

I've tried Dialog.Builder but those windows are instantly dismissed when the user taps outside the range of the check-list.

so right now I have

```
PopupWindow newPop = new PopupWindow(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

That is generating the popup.

Then there is my root element for the popup.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/TopChecklist"> generating check-list here </LinearLayout>
```

So, can anyone recommend a way for the background to be un-touchable and to be faded?

**EDIT:**
Nevermind, I found a trick to get around it.
I changed the layout_width to fill_parent under the XML
Then I changed

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
```

To a rectangle object with color value #88000000

Now the buttons in the background can't be tapped and it all looks faded

Floor is still open for anyone that has a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

An `AlertDialog` should do the trick. Refer to: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question right,
but you could use a normal Dialog like this:

```
public void ShowMyDialog() { 
    Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.MyLayout);
```

and use:

```
myDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);  //Dialog not cancelable when clicked outside dialog
```

or

```
myDialog.setCancelable(false); //Dialog not cancelable with back key
```

and dynamically at your checklist...